# Visual Studio Typescript's IntelliSense default generic

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I've got VS Community 2017, TypeScript 2.5.2 installed but still got this squiggly red line in VS editor here:

```
interface Component<T = {}> {

}
```

Error

```
TS1005 ',' expected
```

Comment: Did you install `TypeScript for Visual Studio` too? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55258

Comment: yes i installed it, still having same issue.

Comment: Then maybe you could get better help by creating an Issue on the github repo? https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues


I'm not getting any error in VS Code, but in VS2017 professional (I'm on TS 2.4.2)

Comment: Default generic types were introduced fairly recently (v2.3). VS probably uses an old version of TypeScript. See [how to update TypeScript in VS 2017](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Updating-TypeScript-in-Visual-Studio-2017)

Comment: Yes, that's right. I had an older VS2017 version which was shipped with TS 2.1. Thought installing a separate package would solve it, but i had to update VS anyway.